# Google Cloud: saving BigQuery results as a .csv file to a *specific* directory on Google Drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-drive-api

After running my SQL query, the "Save Results" button provides a drop-down box, one of whose options is "CSV (Google Drive)". Clicking this causes the file to be saved to an auto-generated directory called `bq-results-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-<something>` in my Google Drive's main directory.

If I use this option often, I'll end up with hundreds of similar folders in my Google Drive main directory. I want to save them to a specific directory without having to manually move them.

Comment: Not possible, once you open the file, you need to move it.

Comment: Great that you asked this question. I also need answer to this question because big query is saving 3 copies of the output csv in the folder it creates without any explanation. These copies will continue to take space if not manually deleted and this annoying deletion is easy if we save it in a more visible destination

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment, please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving-query-results-to-drive): "When you save results to Drive, you cannot choose the location. Results are always saved to the root "My Drive" location."

If you want to control the destination folder, you will need to go through some coding, for instance create a Cloud Function that runs your query and saves the result to GDrive.